# Как определить скорость скачивания в многопоточной программе?

Tags: c#, download, benchmark

Был простой код скачивания:

```
internal static async Task<ImageFile> DownloadFile(Uri uri)
{
  byte[] result;
  WebResponse response;
  var file = new ImageFile();
  var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

  try
  {
    response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
      response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
      result = ms.ToArray();
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex) { }
  if (response.ContentLength == result.LongLength)
    file.Body = result;
  return file;
}
```

Захотелось добавить показатель скорости скачивания. Гугл подсказал, что можно ориентироваться на скорость чтения потока:

```
result = await CopyTo(response.GetResponseStream(), response.ContentLength, progressChanged);

private static async Task<byte[]> CopyTo(Stream from, long totalBytes, Action<DownloadProgress> loadedEvent)
{
  var sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();
  var data = new byte[totalBytes];
  byte[] buffer = new byte[81920];
  int currentIndex = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    int num = await from.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (num != 0)
    {
      Array.Copy(buffer, 0, data, currentIndex, num);
      currentIndex += num;
      loadedEvent?.Invoke(new DownloadProgress(currentIndex, totalBytes, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    }
    else
      break;
  }
  sw.Stop();
  return data;
}
```

Для хранения информации (и прокидывания наверх), завел простую структуру:

```
public struct DownloadProgress
{
  public readonly long BytesReceived;

  public readonly long TotalBytesToReceive;

  public readonly long TimeMs;

  public double GetSpeed()
  {
    var seconds = TimeMs / 1000.0;
    if (seconds > 0)
      return BytesReceived / seconds;
    return 0;
  }

  public DownloadProgress(long received, long total, long time)
  {
    this.BytesReceived = received;
    this.TotalBytesToReceive = total;
    this.TimeMs = time;
  }
}
```

Итого, если качать в один поток, то `GetSpeed` в любой момент времени (кроме первой секунды где то) показывает реальную скорость.

Класс, который качает общую цифру в итоге хранит у себя:

```
    this.Speed = 0;
    var file = await ImageFile.DownloadFile(this.ImageLink, dp => this.Speed = dp.GetSpeed());
    this.Speed = 0;
```

Дальше я думал осталось самое легкое - просто на верхнем уровне сложил все скорости и всё:

```
return this.ActivePages != null && this.ActivePages.Any() ? 
  this.ActivePages.Sum(p => p.Speed) : 0;
```

На деле, получилось очень неприятное поведение:

1. Большую часть времени скорость действительно отображается корректная.
2. Скорость часто скачет, причем разброс иногда превосходит ширину канала. При канале в 650кб\сек цифры скачут от 300кб\сек до 5-8мб\сек.

Если скорость ниже вполне может быть при окончании одной загрузки и начале следующей, то вот превышение ширины канала очевидно невозможно технически.
Возможно я где то округление пропустил, или `Stopwatch` недостаточно точен для таких расчетов?

UPD: таки первое подозрение оправдалось - начальный скачок скорости портил общую статистику. Если метод подсчета скорости сделать вот таким:

```
  public double GetSpeed()
  {
    var seconds = TimeMs / 1000.0;
    if (seconds > 0.1)
      return BytesReceived / seconds;
    return 0;
  }
```

То скорость уже в целом намного адекватнее, выше ширины канала изредка скачки ещё бывают, но уже не больше 5%. Можно увеличить игнорируемое время, тогда скачков не будет совсем.

Осталась проблема с общим показателем. Если для одного потока цифра была достоверной, то с многопоточным скачиванием цифра часто врёт, средняя от показателя получается ниже реальной (общее время на общий объем).

UPD2: минимизировал все расчеты, убрал структуру, вынес логику в статический класс:

```
  public class NetworkSpeed
  {
    public static double TotalSpeed { get { return totalSpeed; } }

    private static double totalSpeed = 0;

    private const uint Seconds = 3;

    private const uint TimerInterval = 1000;

    private static Timer speedTimer = new Timer(state =>
    {
      var now = 0L;
      while (receivedStorage.Value.Any())
      {
        long added;
        if (receivedStorage.Value.TryDequeue(out added))
        {
          now += added;
        }
      }
      lastSpeeds.Value.Enqueue(now);
      totalSpeed = lastSpeeds.Value.Average();
    }, null, 0, TimerInterval);

    private static Lazy<LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>> lastSpeeds = new Lazy<LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>>(() => new LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>(Seconds));

    private static Lazy<ConcurrentQueue<long>> receivedStorage = new Lazy<ConcurrentQueue<long>>();

    public static void Clear()
    {
      while (receivedStorage.Value.Count > 0)
      {
        long dd;
        receivedStorage.Value.TryDequeue(out dd);
      }
      while (lastSpeeds.Value.Count > 0)
      {
        double dd;
        lastSpeeds.Value.TryDequeue(out dd);
      }
    }

    public static void AddInfo(long received)
    {
      receivedStorage.Value.Enqueue(received);
    }

    private class LimitedConcurrentQueue<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>
    {
      public uint Limit { get; }

      public new void Enqueue(T item)
      {
        while (Count >= Limit)
        {
          T deleted;
          TryDequeue(out deleted);
        }
        base.Enqueue(item);
      }

      public LimitedConcurrentQueue(uint limit)
      {
        Limit = limit;
      }
    }
  }
```

В итоге, при скачивании достаточно сообщать, сколько байт было скачано в очередной момент:

```
      NetworkSpeed.AddInfo(num);
```

И всё, показатель `NetworkSpeed.TotalSpeed` будет отображать среднюю за последние 3 секунды скорость. Средний показатель в целом стал более-менее стабильным, правда немного завышает показатели на моих данных. Ну и очевидно, что если тредпул будет перегружен, то таймер вовремя не отработает и скорость начнёт "скакать".

Comment: А почему бы вот это и не выводить: прошедшее время на суммарный загруженный объём?

Comment: @VladD у меня есть кнопка паузы. В текущей реализации скорость реально упадёт до 0. Если я буду делать объем на время (большее 1-2 секунды), то это будет уже средняя скорость и на неё пауза фактически не действует. Пропал интернет - а скорость падать будет медленно, с течением времени. Больше валидаций надо на такую логику.

Comment: Ну, тогда общее количество скачанного за последние X секунд, делённое на Х. Будет, собственно, средняя скорость за последние X секунд.

Comment: @VladD, это мне тоже в голову уже пришло. Попробую. Таймер будет один на это дело соответственно, может точность и повысится.

Comment: Для повышения точности можно ещё сообщения о прогрессе слать с таймстампом.

Comment: @VladD, всмысле, вместо ms? А каким образом это может помочь?

Comment: @VladD переписал на общее кол-во скачанного на общее время, стало чуть лучше, но точность на самом деле всё равно так себе. В среднем, у меня теперь завышение показателей где то на 10-15%. Это лучше чем было, ибо до этого было занижение до 30%, но всё равно очевидно можно как то лучше. Как - пока больше идей нет.

Comment: Хм, на больших скоростях отклонение снижается, гигабайт стянулся и точность отображения аж 99% оказалась. Считать это работающим решением, что ли тогда.

Comment: Хм, странно, что снижение до 30%. А в реальности, может быть так оно и есть? И ещё, как вы считаете? Может, ошибка где-нибудь? Например, не учитываютя те сообщения, которые не успели «долететь» до главного потока? Попробуйте ради интереса увеличить X.

Comment: @VladD 30 было на старом варианте. Текущий до 5% максимум вроде доходит, и то заметно только на узком канале. Широкий канал вроде адекватнее себя ведёт.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Публикую решение, которое меня устроило. Точность итоговой цифры 95-99%.

```
  public class NetworkSpeed
  {
    public static double TotalSpeed { get { return totalSpeed; } }

    private static double totalSpeed = 0;

    private const uint Seconds = 3;

    private const uint TimerInterval = 1000;

    private static Timer speedTimer = new Timer(state =>
    {
      var now = 0L;
      while (receivedStorage.Value.Any())
      {
        long added;
        if (receivedStorage.Value.TryDequeue(out added))
        {
          now += added;
        }
      }
      lastSpeeds.Value.Enqueue(now);
      totalSpeed = lastSpeeds.Value.Average();
    }, null, 0, TimerInterval);

    private static Lazy<LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>> lastSpeeds = new Lazy<LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>>(() => new LimitedConcurrentQueue<double>(Seconds));

    private static Lazy<ConcurrentQueue<long>> receivedStorage = new Lazy<ConcurrentQueue<long>>();

    public static void Clear()
    {
      while (receivedStorage.Value.Count > 0)
      {
        long dd;
        receivedStorage.Value.TryDequeue(out dd);
      }
      while (lastSpeeds.Value.Count > 0)
      {
        double dd;
        lastSpeeds.Value.TryDequeue(out dd);
      }
    }

    public static void AddInfo(long received)
    {
      receivedStorage.Value.Enqueue(received);
    }

    private class LimitedConcurrentQueue<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>
    {
      public uint Limit { get; }

      public new void Enqueue(T item)
      {
        while (Count >= Limit)
        {
          T deleted;
          TryDequeue(out deleted);
        }
        base.Enqueue(item);
      }

      public LimitedConcurrentQueue(uint limit)
      {
        Limit = limit;
      }
    }
  }
```

Как этим пользоваться - на верхнем уровне вызываем `Clear()` когда начинаем или заканчиваем скачивание, чтобы результаты были независимы от других загрузок.
В месте, где происходит реальное скачивание - вызываем метод `AddInfo`, указав сколько байт нам пришло в очередной цикл скачивания. Можно использовать `CopyTo` из шапки или `DownloadProgressChanged` у `WebClient`. Главное передавать именно разницу между предыдущим показателем и текущим.

Точность измерений обеспечивается таймером (`System.Threading.Timer`), а потому, чтобы точность показаний была достоверной, тредпул должен быть свободен для вызова `callback`.

Ну и, понятное дело, результат всех измерений находится в свойстве `TotalSpeed`. Если хочется, можно добавить событие о его изменении, для своевременного отображения в UI. Частота его обновления специально синхронизирована с таймером - иначе цифра меняется слишком часто и пользователь не понимает, какова скорость.